# How to create reusable (React ↔ React Native) components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The task is to make a website on React, and then the same mobile application.
The mobile application will almost completely repeat the web application.

I didn't develop mobile apps before, and now I'm trying to figure it out.
As I understand, the easiest way would be to use React Native for a mobile app. Is that so? Or are there more convenient alternatives? (Not WebView)

I would like to have, as far as possible, a single code base, and reuse React components in React Native.

I see some features that need to be considered:

- Styled Components instead of css
- No display:grid

What else do I need to consider immediately before starting development?

How will React Native react to such web-specific things as :hover in styled components? Will it throw out an error or just ignore it?

What UI frameworks can I use?
For example, I see that Grommet and Rebass use styled components. Will their components work on React Native?

Or for example, antDesign - it has a version for React Native, the syntax of the components is similar in appearance. Can I reuse components from the web version in React Native by simply importing the rn version of antd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.
I can answer from the Grommet perspective, sound like Grommet will work fine for your top requirements, it uses styled-components instead of CSS, and it does support mobile device or different window sizing with its built-in t-shirt sizing mechanism of 'small' (mobile), 'medium' (tablet), 'large' (desktop) and other optional user custom styles.

I'm not sure to what scale you'll need a React Native support, but I was able to build many Grommet mobile applications that support mobile devices without using React-Native.